# Amazon RDS MySQL takes long time to truncate table or alter auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I have a problem with MySQL Amazon RDS. Every time I run command to truncate table or alter table's auto increment, it took long long time and eventually showed timeout.

I'm using Sequel Pro and MySQL Workbench. Both of them can't execute the command.

Does anyone experienced the same problem ? Please help

Comment: Sounds like there is another process open that has a lock on the table.  Could anything else be reading from or writing to that table, possibly stuck within a long running query or an open transaction?

Comment: No. This is development database, and I only work with one other developer. She is not even accessing the database

Comment: Use something like `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to double check that *(that there "shouldn't be" is categorically not the same as "I've checked and there isn't"...)*.  Or just reboot the server to force any open connections to close.  Then try again.  If turning it off and on again works, then there was probably something still open that you didn't know about.  If that doesn't work raise an issue with AWS?